# Cannot check if CGI session is expired

Tags: perl, cgi, session-state

```
my $arr;
%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
for (keys %cookies) {
    $arr = ($cookies{$_});
}

@arr1 = split("=", $arr);
@arr2 = split(";", $arr1[1]);
$cgi_session = CGI::Session->load($arr2[0]);

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

if ($cgi_session->is_expired) {
    print "session expire\n";
}
else {
    print "session valid\n";
}
```

The session is initialized to expire after 1 min but it always goes in else when checking 
if expired. Though the session actually expires as the code does not work after a minute.
i want to check if expired to redirect user to login page.

Comment: It is only polite to `use strict` and `use warnings` on programs that you ask for help with. And you should lay your code out so that it is readable. I have formatted it for you. Please write it so that it works under `strict`

Answer (score 0):

First, there's nothing in your code which show a cookie being set. It's not clear how that's happening.

Second, when you use CGI::Session, you should call `$cgi_session->flush()` before the script exits.

Third, are you sure you want to work out all this by hand, instead of using one of Perl's web frameworks as a starting point?